# Reading data from a text file and building a table with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, io

I have an input file named "animals.txt":

```
sheep 10.5 12.3 4
horse 8.4  11.2 7
cow   13.7 7.2  10
duck  23.2 2.5  23
pig   12.4 4.6  12
```

To put my question simply, I would like to know how to store the 4 columns of data into 4 separate 1 dimensional arrays from the input file.

The output should like something like this...

```
[sheep, horse, cow, duck, pig]
[10.5, 8.4, 13.7, 23.2, 12.4]
[12.3, 11.2, 7.2, 2.5, 4.6]
[4, 7, 10, 23, 12]
```

So far I have figured out how to store all of the data into one large array, but I need to know how to break it down and store each column into its own array instead.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String[] animal = new String[5];
    int index = 0;

    File file = new File("animals.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    while (input.hasNextLine() && index < animal.length) {
        animal[index] = input.nextLine();
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of arrays to store what you need, like:

```
String[][] animal = new String[5][];
```

Then, when you read your file, store an array of all the values, like this:

```
while (input.hasNextLine() && index < animal.length) {
    animal[index] = input.nextLine().split(" "); //split returns an array
    index++;
}
```

Then, when you want to output, just loop over the array of arrays:

```
for (String[] a : animal)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is code for a way to do it - you can cut and paste it into a java project in an IDE like eclipse and run it or put it in a file.java and compile and run it on the command line.  Next step would be to make it fully general to take any input including lines with variable number of columns with no predetermined max and without reading the input file twice or storing it memory as an array or other object.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuildTableWithArrays {

    private static final String separator = "\\s+"; // regex for parsing lines
    private static final int rowWidth = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columns = buildMapWithColumnArrayLists("animals.txt");
        printMap(columns);  // for demo
        // if you want actual arrays
        Map<Integer, String[]> colArrays = buildMapWithColumnArrays(columns);

    }

    public static Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> buildMapWithColumnArrayLists(
        String fileName) {

        ArrayList<String> col0 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> col1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> col2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> col3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columns = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
        columns.put(0, col0);
        columns.put(1, col1);
        columns.put(2, col2);
        columns.put(3, col3);

        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] line = input.nextLine().trim().replaceAll(separator, " ")
                    .split(separator);
                for (int i = 0; i < rowWidth; i++) {
                    if (line[i] == null) {
                        columns.get(Integer.valueOf(i)).add("null");
                    } else {
                        columns.get(Integer.valueOf(i)).add(line[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
            System.out.println(x.getMessage());
        }

        return columns;
    }

    public static void printMap(Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columns) {

        for (int i = 0; i < rowWidth; i++) {
            System.out.println("col" + i + " #elements = "
                + columns.get(Integer.valueOf(i)).size());
            for (String s : columns.get(Integer.valueOf(i))) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public static String[] convertArrayList2Array (ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

        String[] array = new String[arrayList.size()];
        array = arrayList.toArray(array);
        return array;

    }

    public static Map<Integer, String[]> buildMapWithColumnArrays(Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columns) {

        Map<Integer, String[]> cols = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>(); 

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : columns.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
            String[] val = convertArrayList2Array(value);
            cols.put(key,val);
        }

        return cols;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your input file is guaranteed then you can use the scanner to get the data that you need. Start by declaring the 4 arrays that you want with appropriate types.

Then in your while loop use:

```
  input.next()
```

to get a string

```
  input.nextInt()
```

to get an integer and

```
  input.nextDouble()
```

to get a double value. Of course you assign these values to the appropriate array.